# Access a dynamically-set $_POST value

Tags: php, form-submit, isset

I am dynamically creating a number of textfields and I want to insert the values of those fields into a database.  Each textfield is associated with a YouTube video that I pull from the API and it carries a name that is the same as the URL of the YouTube video.

The code I have is:

```
     if($youtube_video_database) {
        foreach ($youtube_video_database as $key => $value) {
          foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            print "<div class='content row'>
              <div class='videos_and_comments col col-lg-12'>
                 <div class='videos col-lg-6'>
                   <iframe width='420' height='315' src='$value' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
                 </div>
                 <div class='videos col-lg-6'>
                  <form method='post' action=''>
                    <textarea class='form-control' name='$value' id='$value' rows='14'></textarea>
                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='submit' id='youtube_comment' value='submit'>
                  </form>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div> ";

             print_r($_POST);
              if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

              print $_POST['$value'];

          }

          }

        }
```

the print_r() gives me:

```
Array
(
[http://www_youtube_com/embed/eWucz8UDoPA] => this is what i want to insert
[submit] => submit
)
```

Both the name and ID of the form carry the URL correctly, however I don't get anything when I try

```
print $_POST['$value'];
```

Really I would like to be able to change the isset() to

```
if (isset($_POST['$value']) ) {}
```

but I won't until I can figure out how to access the value.  I've not included the MySQL statement in the code, I'm happy that the syntax of that is correct I just need to access the values I need!

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
print $_POST['$value'];
```

to this:

```
print $_POST[$value];
```

Since variables and escape sequences (other than \') aren't evaluated in single quotes.

Comment: What did this give you?

Comment: I printed print "<h2> this is value" . $_POST[$value]. "</h2>"; which prints this is value but then nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Just use  $_POST[$value] without quotations.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=hidden name='youtubeurls[]'>  
<textarea class='form-control' name='youtubes[]'>

if(isset($_POST['youtubes'])) for(i=0;i<count($_POST['youtubes']);i++){
    echo $_POST['youtubes'][i];
    echo $_POST['youtubesurls'][i];
    //do whatever you want
}
```